# sqlite3 where exactly database in SQLITE_BUSY state

Tags: c++, sqlite

Where exactly sqlite3 database will be at `SQLITE_BUSY` state for other threads and processes. (db at default mode `SERIALIZE`, `not WAL`)

Simple Example to Illustrate the question:

```
char buffer[] = "SELECT sessionid FROM sessions WHERE something < 1000";
sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, buffer, strlen(buffer), &stmt, 0)

// IS DB SQLITE_BUSY HERE ? PLACE 1

while( sqlite3_step(stmt) == SQLITE_ROW )
{
 // IS DB SQLITE_BUSY HERE ? PLACE 2
}

 // IS DB STILL SQLITE_BUSY HERE? PLACE 3
sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
```

Comment: Preparing a statement does not execute it. The behaviour of implicit transactions is [documented](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html).

Answer (score 0):

I know for a fact that both `sqlite3_prepare_v2` and `sqlite3_step` can error with `SQLITE_BUSY` (the docs say so and I've encountered it many times). The docs are less clear for `sqlite3_finalize` but my impression is that `sqlite3_finalize` is merely for memory management, so it should not do any database access.

`sqlite3_step` is the most likely place for this to happen, since it is what actually performs things like `"INSERT INTO..."` and `"COMMIT"` which tend to be heavy on the database.

SQLite is not terribly helpful when it comes to concurrency. By default, it does not even provide any fairness guarantees (although you can write them yourself as long as your concurrency is happening within the same process).

Comment: seems by default sqlite is in seralized mode if combiled woth thread_sade  flag. so its thread safe by default...

Comment: I was referring more to how SQLite handles concurrent connections to the same database. Unlike heavier duty SQL servers, SQLite is pretty "light" in how much it helps you in this area.